# SSRS - Lookupset return #Error

Tags: sql-server, function, reporting-services, lookup

**My Configuration:**

DB1 - MSSQL 2000

DB1 - MSSQL 2005

SSRS 2008 R2

I have two **datasets**:

Dataset1 - query from DB1

Dataset1 - query from DB2

So I'm trying to build a report which will compare two tables using LookUpSet function. The problem is that the specified destination field return `#Error` as value.

Here is the LookupSet function that I'm using:

```
=lookupset(Fields!IMNumber.Value,Fields!IMnumber.Value,Fields!client.Value,"Dataset2")
```

Each table contains the column IMNumber.
When I run the report, the result for the Client column return #Error as result.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your "Dataset2" returns more than one value for the value. In this case you can JOIN the values with `,`

So the expression would be:

```
=JOIN(LookupSet(Fields!IMNumber.Value,Fields!IMnumber.Value,Fields!client.Value,"Dataset2"),",")
```

Comment: Hello Arulkumar, thanks for the quick reply. I have tried your solution. So the result return ~ 600 rows, and now some of the fields are just empty and the rest same thing #Error

Comment: @kekimian Then you need to hide that textbox visibility. Simply right click the textbox, in textbox visibility apply the expression `=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!IMnumber.Value),True,False)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now its return me the following error  `Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.`

Comment: I think that the Lookupset function doesn't work, because the result contains always 600 rows with or without using the Lookupset.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one Dataset in your report, you should give along every field you reference. You are missing the second DataSet Reference.

As Example:

```
=JOIN(LookupSet((Fields!IMNumber.Value, "DataSet1"),(Fields!IMnumber.Value,"Dataset2")),",")
```

Or further your report `TextBox` got an incorrect formatting in it.

Check it with
`-> Textbox Properties -> Number`